# found problem Django data transfer by render request to template

Tags: python, html, django

I have tried a several times but can't find anything wrong. Here is my code.
[This is from views.py][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0d4a.png

[This is from html file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF5W5.png)

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your template it should be:

```
{% if title != '' %}
    <title>Django blog - {{ title }}</title>
{% else %}
    <title>Django blog</title>
{% endif %}
```

title is a key inside your context dictionary therefore to access its value just use {{ title }} not {{ title.values }}.